# Flutter IOS app overheating and increasing GPU with random crash

Tags: flutter

We have a social media app with a reel option while playing videos on iOS mobile, which gets overheated and increases the GPU. I am using the better player, which has random crashes. In Android, working fine. Only iPhones have this issue

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: **-[__NSArrayM InsertObject:atIndex:]`

Thanks in advance

I tried a reusable better player controller, but No luck

Answer (score 1):

I had used the

> BackdropFilter

widget, which causes the GPU to increase.

Now app working fine without overheating and GPU is not took much. Because IOS take more GPU for render BackdropFilter widget.